# TM symbol image instead of unicode special character in woocommerce emails

Tags: html, unicode, woocommerce

I run a webshop where we sell products that are trademarked and protected. This means that all product names contain the ™ symbol. Woocommerce emails takes the product title for the order confirmation emails, but has problems with visualising the ™ symbol. It becomes an image. I have exchanged all ™ symbols in the product titles with the appropriate html entity `&#x2122;`, but it's not helping.

[image]

What can I do to improve this?

Comment: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/17823

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The woocommerce emails, or wp_mail, use an emoji for these symbols. So if you want to disable this, you can remove emoji from wp_mail and it will use the html unicode ™ symbol instead.

Add the following line in the bottom of your `functions.php`:

```
function disable_emojis() {
    remove_filter( 'wp_mail', 'wp_staticize_emoji_for_email' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'disable_emojis' );
```

Tested it, and it works.